Having the child's scroll view take precedence over the parent's when mouse is over the child
(I don't think this is a dup of WinUI 3 ListView (or ScrollView) inside a ScrollView)
If there are controls with scroll views (e.g. ListView) in another control with a scroll view (e.g., ItemsView), when both are scrollable, hovering the mouse over a child scroll view (e.g., the ListView), the parent's scroll view takes precedence and scrolls instead of the intended.
How to make the child control's scroll view (that the mouse is over when scrolling) take precedence instead? Is there a standard way like setting some properties? Or do you have to do it in code (i.e., disable the parent scroll when the mouse is over one of the children)?
Thx

That works with nested ListViews but not with ListViews inside a ItemsView.

What are you referring to that works?
Perhaps I should use an ItemsRepeater instead, will that work? I don't know what the difference is.

I mean you can use the mouse scroll on ListViews inside a ListView but not on ListViews inside a ItemsView. I haven't dug deeper or tried other options, like the ItemsRepeater.
